# Use Windows Phone 8 internet connection on desktop trough USB or Bluetooth

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I would like to use Windows Phone 8 internet connection on my desktop computer, it doesn't have wireless network card so I can't use phone's wireles access point.

So only other options are Bluetooth and USB cable, is it possible to use those for phone internet connection sharing ?

Comment: As a heads up, this process is called "Tethering". You might be able to find more information on google under the search "Windows 8 phone USB tethering".

Comment: See also: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3944/106

Comment: @RowlandShaw cool :), could you please make an answer so I can accept it since it's much better than currently accepted asnwer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends if your phone contract provider allows this. I wasn't able to until I upgraded my contract. They may charge you for tethering.

Otherwise:
Navigate to Settings, System, Internet Sharing. Turn sharing on and plug your phone in to your computer with the usb cable.

Comment: I did that before, it only gives me choice to import files and photos, so I suppose that I must call my provider, thanks

Comment: This method allows other devices to share your PC connection. I think the question is asking the other way around!